# How to exclude a maven variable (same syntax as ksh variable)

Tags: java, maven, ksh

i'm facing a sketchy problem, i have a ksh script that gets a ${USER} variable from a configuration file. i can't change the name of the variable, but since it's also the name of an environment variable in UNIX, the value gets replaced by the Maven builder.

Is there a way to exclude this variable from being changed by Maven? 
Thanks.

```
Maven variables : ${var}
ksh variable :${var}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this file is in `src/main/resources` and being filtered by the normal Maven resources plugin, you may configure an [escape character](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/escape-filtering.html) to prevent this. Add configuration for the resources plugin and define the escape char to use.

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version><fillInLatestVersion></version>
    <configuration>
      ...
      <escapeString>\</escapeString>
      ...
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Then configure the resources file to escape anything Maven shouldn't replace.

```
Maven variables : ${var}
ksh variable : \${var}
```